# How to solve a linear system using red black order gauss seidel?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to parallelize Gauss-Seidel algorithm using red-black ordering. I've been searching examples in how to use the Discrete Poisson Equation to program gauss-seidel but I have not found examples. I understand more or less the concept of red-black ordering but I don't understand it a lot.
The part that I don't understand well is how is the form of the matrix that I need to input.

Comment: How are you stuck on this?  The input is the same form as for normal Gauss-Seidel: a square matrix ***A*** and a values vector ***b***, which you'll use to solve ***Ax = b***.  Since you're writing the code, the specific communication formats are up to you.

Comment: The Poisson part is similarly constrained: you need the main diagonal's square matrix, m x m, where m is the row count of the system grid.  The repetition factor is similarly determined by the grid, and the just-off-diagonal *I* matrices are also m x m.

Comment: I mean, how can I manage the boundaries in my matrix? and what restrictions does my matrix have to have to be compute using the equation of red black order? for example this linear system: A = [1 5 2; -1 -2 7; 2 8 -2] , x = [x1 x2 x3], b = [1 17 6] can be solve using the Discrete Poisson Equation of red black ordering?